# Why am I Bean.getAccountname()' on a null object reference

Tags: android

I want to do a expandablelistview but when I click on group list it crashes.

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.tooozy.accountbook, PID: 16291
    java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String com.tooozy.accountbook.model.AccountDetailBean.getAccountname()' on a null object reference
        at com.tooozy.accountbook.Adapter.Adapter_AccountItem.getChildView(Adapter_AccountItem.java:98)
        at android.widget.ExpandableListConnector.getView(ExpandableListConnector.java:451)
....
```

here are my expandablelistview adapter code
according to the first error message  (com.tooozy.accountbook.Adapter.Adapter_AccountItem.getChildView(Adapter_AccountItem.java:98))

```
@Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        ChildHolder childHolder;
        if (convertView == null){
            convertView = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_contact_child,parent,false);
            childHolder = new ChildHolder();
            childHolder.tv_rv_accountname = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_tv_accountname);
            childHolder.tv_rv_amount = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_tv_amount);
            childHolder.tv_rv_date = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lv_tv_date);
            convertView.setTag(childHolder);
        }else {
            childHolder = (ChildHolder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        AccountDetailBean detailBean = Child.get(Group.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosition);

        childHolder.tv_rv_accountname.setText(detailBean.getAccountname());  /**(Adapter_AccountItem.java:98)**/
        childHolder.tv_rv_amount.setText(detailBean.getAmount());
        childHolder.tv_rv_date.setText(detailBean.getDate());
        return convertView;
    }
```

I can see the group and put message into it, but I can't expand it[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/bLrc8.png)

here id my list view code

```
 listview = view.findViewById(R.id.expandablelistview);
        Group = new ArrayList<>();
        Child = new HashMap<>();
        Group.add("f");
        Group.add("s");
        Group.add("t");
        Group.add("f");
        Group.add("fif");
        Group.add("six");
        Group.add("sev");
        Group.add("eight");
        AllData = MyApplication.mdbmaster.mAccountDetailDao.mare();
        Child.put(Group.get(0),AllData.get(0));
        Child.put(Group.get(1),AllData.get(1));
        Child.put(Group.get(2),AllData.get(2));
        Child.put(Group.get(3),AllData.get(3));
        Child.put(Group.get(4),AllData.get(4));
        Child.put(Group.get(5),AllData.get(5));
        Child.put(Group.get(6),AllData.get(6));
        Child.put(Group.get(7),AllData.get(7));

        adapter_accountItem = new Adapter_AccountItem(Group, Child,this.getContext());
        listview.setAdapter(adapter_accountItem);
```

Comment: detailBean is null. Try investigating how you initialize it!

Comment: Debug your code and you can find the error. Maybe you are trying to get null object from detailBean